# Catching a query exception?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a slug column in my database, it's unique.

If I try and store another row with a non unique slug I get a QueryException error.

I catch the error, and hope to return an error message something along the lines that "slug exists".

```
try {
    User::create($data);
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    //return the error
}
```

The above is fine, but I'm just wondering, what if another QueryException is thrown, not to do with the duplicate slug and i return a duplicate slug error message incorrectly.

Is there a way to find out what the query exception was and return an error message based on this? i know the exception provides its own message but I was hoping for something a little more user friendly.

Comment: You can catch the generic `Exception` instead of specifying an exception. You can even chain them, if you want.

Comment: aynber - ok catch the general exception, then what? how do I figure out if its for a dup key?

Comment: @panthro Why are you even following this approach, why are you not validating the slug before its being sent for creation? I believe that is what laravel validations are for? Please prefer doing something like -> `$rules = ['slug' => 'exists:users'];`

Comment: Doing that you would have to check that the error returned was the specific error code related to Duplicate entry, you will have to look that one up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To check if you got a `QueryException` because of a duplicate, check if `$e->getCode()` equals to `23000`.

When a duplicate occurs due to a constraint, MySQL will issue `signal SQLSTATE 23000` which you can use to determine what exactly went wrong. You can implement your own signal in MySQL to signal about various errors (via triggers etc)

Example:

```
try {
    User::create($data);
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    if($e->getCode() === '23000') {
        // you got the duplicate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check errorInfo of the exception object

It looks like this..

```
+errorInfo: array:3 [▼
0 => "23000"
1 => 1062
2 => "Duplicate entry 'abc@gmail.com' for key 'users_email_unique'"
```

You can write following code in catch..

```
 try{}
    catch(QueryException $qe){
    If ($qe->errorInfo[0] == "23000" && $qe->errorInfo[1] == "1062"){
        return "Your message"
    }else{
        return "General Message"
    } 
}
```